# Difference between sqlContext.sql and sqlContext.setConf

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What is difference between `sqlContext.sql` and `sqlContext.setConf`, and which one should I prefer?

```
scala> sqlContext.sql("set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=15")

scala> sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "10")
```

Answer (score 3):

`sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "10")` will set the property parameter for `whole application` before `logicalPlan` is generated.

`sqlContext.sql("set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=15")` will also set the property but only for `particular query` and is generated at the time of `logicalPlan` creation.

Choosing between them depends on what your requirement is.